What role does CaCl2 play in a gelation medium?
To produce sodium alginate beads coated with chitosan, following procedure was undertaken:

Sodium alginate was dissolved in distilled water at a concentration of 4% (...) The gelation medium was prepared by dissolving chitosan (1% w/v) in one percent acetic acid, followed by addition of CaCl2 at the concentration of 4% (w/v). The sodium alginate solution was added dropwise into gelation medium [and cured] *

Why do you have to add CaCl2 to the solution that makes the gelation medium?
As far as I know the CaCl2 will dissociate into $\ce{Ca^2+}$ and $\ce{Cl}$ ions. How does this aid in getting the chitosan molecules to the sodium alginate bead?

Source: S.K. Bajpai, R. Tankhiwale / Reactive & Functional Polymers 66
(2006) 645–65


Likely, the $\ce{CaCl2}$ induces precipitation, or gelation, in this case. This is called salting out. Another example is using salting out to gel poly(N-isopropylacrylamide) for 3D-printing.
Simply put, $\ce{CaCl2}$ is hygroscopic, "stealing" water from the sodium alginate, effectively drying it to a gel. $\ce{CaCl2}$ is so hygroscopic that, when used to reduce humidity, the solid particles eventually dissolve in the absorbed water! This is termed deliquescence.
